# Monitor not recognized by other devices after having connected my raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspbian, display, pi-4, signal

I have a weird problem and I simply can't find any solution to it:

I use a Fujitsu Siemens monitor with a dvi to hdmi cable which works just fine with all my devices. However, after I connected my raspberry pi 4 (running Raspbian), the monitor doesn't work with any of the other devices anymore (neither Windows 10 nor MacOS). It still works fine with the raspberry pi though (no matter what distro I use).

When I say "it doesn't work", I mean that the monitor is not detected by the other devices and is going into sleep mode due to a missing signal. I have already tried to play around with the resolution while connected to the raspberry pi and have also put the settings back to default.

Has anyone of you guys encountered a similar problem in the past and knows how to fix it?

Comment: I had an LG that would not change out of VGA after using adapters once.  I solved it by pulling the plug (not just turn off) for a good 2 hours and that reset the control board.  A quick unplug did not help - I assume internal capacitors kept the config valid for a bit.  I do find the newer ‘auto-config’ monitors a pain - give me a manual config any day...  you could look at the cec-client software and see if it tells you anything and make sure you remove all adapters from the back when changing modes as they can signal the screen (sometimes by data, sometimes by a ground / power loop).